# Present simple and present continuous with NOW

Tags: tense

What difference does “now” make when used with the Present Simple and the Present Continuous?

1. Do you smoke now?
2. Are you smoking now? (not right now but these days)

PS: I am not fully satisfied with my question, so I will edit it.
Another example:

- We both know that you smoked when we went to school. Do you smoke now? or Are you smoking now?

(Which one is correct?)

Answer (score 1):

1 asks whether the person concerned is a smoker (not whether s/he is smoking at this moment).

2 asks whether the person concerned is smoking (tobacco/cannabis etc) at the moment.

Comment: 2 can mean that it's happening at the moment but I am asking about a different meaning. Continuous can be used when something is happening these days. If I wanted to know whether the person is a smoker why would I add NOW?

Comment: the present continuous in that sense is used to express a new habit, so maybe you started smoking recently and someone sees you smoking and says: "you're smoking now?" because it is a new habit. Out of interest, where did you find that sentence?

Comment: I made it up. How does it differ from "Do you smoke now?"